# DBNull при добавлении записи в БД

Tags: c#

Я добавляю в БД запись, стоки беру из textbox. Если textbox не заполнен, то нужно поставить значение NULL.

Первый вариант (рабочий):

```
string patronymic = textBoxPatronymic.Text; if(patronymic != "") { command.Parameters.AddWithValue(patronymic );} else {command.Parameters.AddWithValue(DBNull.Value);}
```

Но хотелось, чтобы код был более читабельным, сделал так:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@patronymic", string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(patronymic) ? DBNull.Value : patronymic);
```

или

```
command.Parameters.Add("@patronymic", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(patronymic) ? DBNull.Value : patronymic;
```

Но в результате ошибка:

> Не удается определить тип условного выражения, так как неявного
>   преобразования между "System.DBNull" и "string" не существует.

В интернете советуют этот способ, но у меня он не работает. В чем моя ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь вернуть неодинаковые типы в

```
string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(patronymic) ? DBNull.Value : patronymic
```

Так делать нельзя.

Предлагаю вам явно привести каждый из них к базовому `object`

```
string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(patronymic) ? (object)DBNull.Value : (object)patronymic
```